# Why my apache server keep on stopping?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, php5

My apache server keep on stopping. If i restart it will work for 5-6 hours again it goes to down. These are system and apache configuration details.

```
Apache : 2.4 version
PHP : 5.6.30 
System Configuration :256GB RAM,80 cores intel processors
MPM Module : mpm_event 
MPM Config file :
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers    10
    # MinSpareThreads   25
    #MaxSpareThreads    75
    ThreadLimit      64
    ThreadsPerChild     64
    ServerLimit     62
    MaxRequestWorkers   3968
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 10000
</IfModule>
Avg Concurrent requests :500
Max Concurrent requests :1600
total customers : 250000
```

Error logs :

```
[Thu Jul 06 13:33:33.132472 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 105638:tid 140420591675136] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :8080: (polling)
```

And sometimes there are no errors or access logs.

Comment: If you don't get enough information in the logs increase the log level. The mentioned error however indicates a problem with the backend server the apache proxies to.

Comment: Do all the httpd processes vanish? httpd can't stop itself.